# How do I update a Craft website without losing data?

Tags: craft3, database

I have an existing website built with Craft CMS. I made a few changes locally and now I want to update the 'live' website. The problem is that I added a couple of fields and sections but I can't just replace the live database with the one I am currently working with locally because the content in the live database is more up to date and I don't want to override that content.

So how can I get those new fields and sections in the live/production database without losing any data in said database?

Answer (score 2):

You can always add the fields manually to the live site, works best imo if you made a limited amount of changes.

If you have made a lot of changes, a plugin like [Firstborn's Migration Manager](https://github.com/Firstborn/Craft-Migration-Manager) could do the trick. I have never used it personally, but it seems to do a lot of great things and uses the built-in migration system of Craft 3. Probably worth to give it a spin. There's also a Craft 2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Another plugin that should do the job is [Architect](https://github.com/Pennebaker/craft-architect)